# Can i make an ORM one-to-many relation an explicit class of?

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have an user and a privileg class. The user can have many privileges. So far so good.

I have some similiar of these relation to the user class. But i don't want to clutter the user with all these stuff.

So i thought it would be a good idea to make the relation between user and privileg explicit.
I would like to get a class UserPrivilges with a one-to-one relation to user and a one-to-many relation to privileges.

Would be nice to get some feedback if this is possible.

Thx
Per

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to group several OneToMany associations inside a separate class, and have an instance of this class inside User. But semantically, these associations are associations between the User and other entities.

If so, you should keep your database scheam as is, and simply use an embedded object inside User to group your associations:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserPrivileges
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Privilege> somePrivileges;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Privilege> someOtherPrivileges;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Privilege> yetOtherPrivileges;
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @Embedded
    private UserPrivileges privileges;
}
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-component) for more details.